# Duvida sobre UML

Tags: uml

estou com uma dúvida sobre a ligação dessas tabelas da imagem abaixo. Aquilo que eu destaquei é realmente uma associação??

A figura correta da seta não seria assim > para ser uma associação? E o que quer dizer ali aquela seta?

E a outra ligação que está tracejada o que é e qual o sentido dela?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, realmente não está dentro dos melhores padrões, mas parece que Window é uma subclasse de Glyph, e faz a utilização do método Draw fornecendo uma instância de Window por meio da execução do método Redraw.

implementado seria algo do tipo:

```
public class Window extends Glyph {
   public void Redraw() {
      // Toda implementação de Draw...
   }
}
```

O pontilhado no caso seria uma exemplificação do uso de Glyph por meio de Window.

```
public class Window extends Glyph {
   public void Redraw() {
      super.Draw(this);
   }

   public void Iconify() { }

   public void Lower() { }

   public void DrawLine() { }

}
```

Comment: Ata, entao Window extends Glyph atraves daquela seta na imagem, certo?
E no caso a DialogWindow extends Window atraves daquele triangulo? No caso as 2 notaçoes indicam a mesma coisa? Eu entendi o que tu quis dizer, mas ao analizar o DialogWindow ficou estranho essas 2 notações

Comment: Isso aí, a linha com seta indica a relação do extends ou implements, depende de como as classes foram modeladas, O pontilhado deve mesmo ser uma instrução de uso, Já no caso DialogWindow com certeza está errado, pois tá ambíguo, ele tenta mostrar que DialogWindow herda de Window por meio o owner, através da seta da direita, mas a junção das três relações com o triângulo já faz isso...